# Different formatting so that the URL and DOI number are also displayed

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperref, ieeetran, urls

I am currently working on a scientific paper and would like to display the URL and the requested date, as well as further information and, if available, the DOI number (below are examples of what I have and what I would like to have) I work with Citavi and use the ieee access citation style. Within Word, I get an output that I would love to have within Latex in Overleaf, unfortunately the output is not my idea. Does anyone have any idea how I have to change this so that it is the way I want it to be?

**bibliography.bib**

```
@article{Gandhi.27.5.2018,
 abstract = {Artificial Intelligence has become prevalent recently. People across different disciplines are trying to apply AI to make their tasks a lot easier. For example, economists are using AI to predict$\ldots$},
 author = {Gandhi, Rohith},
 year = {27.5.2018},
 title = {Introduction to Machine Learning Algorithms: Linear Regression},
 url = {\url{https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-machine-learning-algorithms-linear-regression-14c4e325882a}},
 urldate = {12.02.2021},
 journal = {Towards Data Science},
 file = {}
}


@article{Cock.2011,
 author = {de Cock, Dean},
 year = {2011},
 title = {Ames, Iowa: Alternative to the Boston Housing Data as an End of Semester Regression Project},
 volume = {19},
 number = {3},
 journal = {Journal of Statistics Education},
 doi = {\url{10.1080/10691898.2011.11889627}},
 file = {}
}
```

**main.tex**

```
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Some Text ~\cite{Cock.2011}. And more Text ~\cite{Gandhi.27.5.2018}.
.
.
.
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{bibliography}


\end{document}
```

**What I want**

```
Literaturverzeichnis

[1] D. de Cock, “Ames, Iowa: Alternative to the Boston Housing Data as an End of Semester Regression Project,” Journal of Statistics Education, vol. 19, no. 3, 2011, doi: 10.1080/10691898.2011.11889627.
[2] R. Gandhi, “Introduction to Machine Learning Algorithms: Linear Regression,” Towards Data Science, 27 May., 2018. https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-machine-learning-algorithms-linear-regression-14c4e325882a (accessed: 12-Feb-21).
```

**What I got**

```
Literaturverzeichnis

[1]  D. de Cock, “Ames, iowa: Alternative to the boston housing data as an end of semesterregression project,”Journal of Statistics Education, vol. 19, no. 3, 2011.
[2]  R. Gandhi, “Introduction to machine learning algorithms: Linear regression,”TowardsData Science, 27.5.2018.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `ieeetr` bibliography style is one of BibTeX's original bib style, hasn't changed significantly since the mid-1980s, and thus predates the invention of the WWW and, *a fortiori*, the idea to include URL strings in bibliographic references. Try using the `IEEEtran` bib style instead. But if you do, be sure to change all instances of `url = {\url{...}}` to `url = {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main sugggestion is that you replace the ancient, almost pre-historic, `ieeetr` bib style with the `IEEEtran` bib style.

I would further like to suggest you fix several, minor errors in the bibliographic entries. For instance, the entry type `@article` is not appropriate for the `gandhi` entry, as it wasn't published in a scholarly journal. Do also encase place names in curly braces to prevent them from getting converted to lowercase; some examples: `Ames`, `Iowa`, and `Boston`. I would also remove the `\url{...}` wrapper from the arguments of the `url` field names.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{bibliography.bib}
@misc{Gandhi.27.5.2018,
 abstract= {Artificial Intelligence has become prevalent recently. People across different disciplines are trying to apply AI to make their tasks a lot easier. For example, economists are using AI to predict$\ldots$},
 author  = {Gandhi, Rohith},
 year    = 2018,
 title   = {Introduction to Machine Learning Algorithms: Linear Regression},
 url     = {https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-machine-learning-algorithms-linear-regression-14c4e325882a},
 urldate = {12.02.2021},
 howpublished = {Towards Data Science},
 file    = {}
}

@article{Cock.2011,
 author = {de Cock, Dean},
 year   = 2011,
 title  = {{Ames, Iowa}: Alternative to the {Boston} Housing Data as an End of Semester Regression Project},
 volume = {19},
 number = {3},
 journal= {Journal of Statistics Education},
 url    = {https://doi.org/10.1080/10691898.2011.11889627},
 file   = {}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\addto\extrasngerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}}

\usepackage{xurl} % <-- more modern than 'url'
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
Some text~\cite{Cock.2011}. And more text~\cite{Gandhi.27.5.2018}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick help! The only thing missing is `(accessed: 12-Feb-21)` , i.e. the date when I called the url. How could I still display this?

Comment: @Cathi - The `IEEEtran` bib style doesn't recognize (and hence ignores) the `urldate` field name. I suggest changing `urldate = {12.02.2021},` to `note = {accessed: 12-Feb-21},`.